# Json containing '@' angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, javascript-objects

Quick question.

I have a json file:

```
{
   "RentalCore": {
                "@PickUpDate": "2014-09-22T10:00:00Z",
                "@ReturnDateT": "2014-10-06T10:00:00Z",
                "Location": {
                    "@Name": "NY - Airport"
                },
                "ReturnLocation": {
                    "@Name": "NY - Airport"
                }
            }
}
```

Normally if you have an object you'd access its objects with . notation.

But I can't access @PickUpDate etc. Elements that contain '@'.

Could someone shed me some light on this?

get error : **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

if I try and use dot notation to access @PickUpDate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access via `bracket []` syntax. In JS, if you can't access property with `.` syntax, do it via brackets and pass property name as a string.

```js
var obj = {
   "RentalCore": {
                "@PickUpDate": "2014-09-22T10:00:00Z",
                "@ReturnDateT": "2014-10-06T10:00:00Z",
                "Location": {
                    "@Name": "NY - Airport"
                },
                "ReturnLocation": {
                    "@Name": "NY - Airport"
                }
            }
} 

console.log(obj.RentalCore['@PickUpDate']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to access the object properties value which can not be accessed using dot(`.`) notation.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "RentalCore": {
        "@PickUpDate": "2014-09-22T10:00:00Z",
        "@ReturnDateT": "2014-10-06T10:00:00Z",
        "Location": {
            "@Name": "NY - Airport"
        },
        "ReturnLocation": {
            "@Name": "NY - Airport"
        }
    }
} 

console.log(jsonObj.RentalCore['@ReturnDateT']);
```